# Error in Passing Data in View in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter

I'm storing an SQL query result in a `$data` variable and passing it to a `search_view` like this from my model:

```
        $this->db->like('LOWER(title)', strtolower($query));
        $q = $this->db->get('questions');
        $data = $q->row_array();
        $this->load->view('search_view', array('data' => $data));
```

And I am trying to display all results in my view using following structure:

```
<?php if ($data['search_type'] == 'question') { 
        foreach ($data as $question) {
?>


<div class="question-result">
    <h2><?php echo $question['title']; ?></h2>
    <p>Posted by: <a href="#"><?php echo $question['username']; ?>username</a></p>
    <p>Date Posted: <?php echo $question['date']; ?></p>
</div>


<?php } } ?>
```

Where $data['search_type'] is something I need to check to see what type of search was performed, this bit is tested and works fine, no need to worry about it, however

I get an illegal string offset error for all variables like username, title and date that I use.

eddit* example dump:

```
array(7) { ["question_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["title"]=> string(19) "First Question Ever" ["content"]=> string(13) "Hello Content" ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-01-03 15:08:30" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "14" ["username"]=> string(4) "Ilya" ["search_type"]=> string(8) "question" }
```

for some reason this is not returning more than one question, although there should be more for a search performed.

Comment: Preface your snippet with `var_dump($data);` to see what you actually got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use another foreach since its not in another dimension anymore. Once you've used `->row_array()` only one row is returned.

```
<?php if ($data['search_type'] == 'question') { ?>

<div class="question-result">
    <h2><?php echo $data['title']; ?></h2>
    <p>Posted by: <a href="#"><?php echo $data['username']; ?>username</a></p>
    <p>Date Posted: <?php echo $data['date']; ?></p>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

If you expect to have more results then use `->result_array()` instead:

```
$data = $q->result_array();
```

Then on view:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $question): ?>
    <?php if ($question['search_type'] == 'question') { ?>
        <div class="question-result">
            <h2><?php echo $question['title']; ?></h2>
            <p>Posted by: <a href="#"><?php echo $question['username']; ?>username</a></p>
            <p>Date Posted: <?php echo $question['date']; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or might as well just add `$this->db->where('search_type', 'question')` so you wouldn't have to put an if inside the foreach in above loop.

Comment: Fixed the issue where I was only getting one result now I can see both and formated correctly however after that I still get the errors :/

Comment: @Ilya could you elaborate those errors, which are working and which are not? `however after that I still get the errors :/` its hard to guess on my side :)